# SQLite select where all columns are not null

Tags: sqlite

I have column1, column2, column3, column4, column5 and so on.

If I know that one column is not null, I can use this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE columnA IS NOT NULL;
```

But now I want to select rows where all the columns are not null.

How to write is query easily?

Comment: I am sorry but I am having trouble understanding your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the query look like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE NOT column1 IS NULL AND NOT column2 IS NULL...
```

Comment: but if I have many column ,I have to write each column not nul one by one .Is there a eazy way to write?

Comment: once write this long query and create a view on this table then other queries will be easy. other queries must be on that view.

Comment: I agree with the author, this looks pretty weird